# Facing problem while printing KeyCode using jQuery

Tags: jquery

I have a small requirement that is to print the Keycode when any key is pressed.
Below is my code..  But it doesn't seems to work, Please someone help me

```
$('document').keyup(function() 
{
alert(event.keyCode);
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are looking for a small utility to grab the key codes, you could do this... which has the advantage of not having to click the `ok` on the `alert`.

html

```
<input />
<div></div>
```

script

```
$('input').keyup(function(){
    var kc = event.keyCode;
    $('div').html(kc);
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/jasongennaro/neUFS/1/

Answer (score 4):

Try this instead

```
$(document).keyup(function(e) 
{
alert(e.keyCode);
});
```

Here is a demo http://jsfiddle.net/NuRWB/

Comment: E.g., be sure to declare the event argument (you can call it `event` if you want; Amir called it `e` above).

Comment: And don't put document in single quotes!

Comment: Yes, better than my (now deleted) answer :-) +1

Comment: @andyb ha sorry! I feel your pain when an answer is slightly different and gets more upvotes. :)

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$(document).keyup(function(event) 
{
alert(event.keyCode);
});
```

Note that the quote marks around "document" have been removed. This is because you need to pass the JavaScript `document` object to jQuery, rather than a string.

You also need to pass in `event` as an argument to the event handler function.

Here is an [example fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/w2Vzu/6/) showing this working (make sure you click in the "Result" frame to give it focus, then press any key).

Comment: Still need to declare the `event` argument. Your example will only work on IE and browsers like Chrome that throw IE-specific code a bone.

Comment: Missing event param. See my answer.

Comment: @T.J. Crowder - Good point, I'm using Chrome so I didn't notice the missing argument when I ran the fiddle.